# Is there a way to use swift cocoa pods and objective C cocoa pods in same project?

Tags: objective-c, swift2, cocoapods

Right now I am using MagicalRecord in my swift project. I have bridge header file, and my pod file looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod 'MagicalRecord'
```

I would like to use Alamofire instead of AFNetworking. When i insert this line into my pod file MagicalRecord doesn't work:

```
use_frameworks!
```

EDIT: A little more info

By doesn't work i mean the compiler / linker does not recognize MR classes. Here is the second Pod file:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'MagicalRecord'
```

Bridge header is same in both cases:

```
#import <MagicalRecord/MagicalRecord.h>
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work.

Comment: Post your pod file and your bridging header.

Comment: Try `@import MagicalRecord;` instead of `#import ...`. -- And when using from Swift code you have to use `import MagicalRecord` directly in the Swift file.

Comment: Actually you can't do it like this. @import causes error in bridge header file. And adding import MagicalRecord in swift file also causes error. The problem is, before swift all pods were static libraries, and now pods like alamofire are dynamic frameworks. I have managed to implement one or the other, but not together in same project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the README in the [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) github project they recommend to create a Podfile with the following format:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
```

Just add at the end of that Podfile:

```
pod 'MagicalRecord'
```

And then when you need to use MagicalRecord just do:

```
import MagicalRecord
```

in the file needed.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? Because this is exacly what i did, and linker does not recognize magical record. For example try calling MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStack(), it will produce error

Comment: I updated the answer with how you need to use it. Please lmk if that works for you.